# Column sorting check of subcategory of data

Tags: excel, formula, columnsorting

I Have this excel table with me, which contains article types and their size against it, I want to check whether for each article type the sizes are sorted in ascending order or not, by adding a column with indicators as SORTED, NOT SORTED, UNIQUE 
I want to do it with **Excel formula**

```
     A      B    C
1**ARTICLE SIZE STATUS**
2   A       10   SORTED
3   B       11   SORTED
4   A       12   SORTED
5   A       14   NOT SORTED
6   C       11   SORTED
7   D       12   UNIQUE
8   C       13   SORTED
9   A       13   NOT SORTED
10  B       15   NOT SORTED
11  B       14   NOT SORTED
```

I tried to apply =IF($A2=$A3:$A$11,IF($B2ATTACHED IMAGE OF DATASET

Comment: Please find the Caps lock key on your keyboard and turn it off. Using all caps on the internet is like SHOUTING and considered not polite.

Comment: Can you explain the rules for what is sorted and what isn't? Why is C=13 sorted, but B=15 is not sorted? The difference to the previous C value is 2 and the difference to the previous B value is also 2, so the logic is not that "sorted" means the next number. So, what is the logic?? Also, A = 10 to A=12 is sorted, but A=12 to A=14 is not sorted? What is the logic???

Comment: The sorted data should be A 10,12,13,14 But since it's present in the order A 10,12,14,13 The A 13 &14 Should be marked as not sorted

Answer (score 1):

Uses MAXIFS() so you need Microsoft365.

Formula in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11;B2)=1;"UNIQUE";IF(OR(MAXIFS($C$1:C1;$B$1:B1;B2)>C2;AND(MAXIFS(C3:$C$11;B3:$B$11;B2)<C2;COUNTIF(B3:$B$11;B2)>0));"NOT SORTED";"SORTED"))
```

[image]

### **EDIT**

here is a solution for none 365 users.
It is an MATRIX-FORMULA, so use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula:

for C2 use this

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11;B2)=1;"UNIQUE";IF(OR(IFERROR(MAX($C$1:C1*($B$1:B1=B2));0)>C2;AND(IFERROR(MAX(C3:$C$11*(B3:$B$11=B2));0)<C2;COUNTIF(B3:$B$11;B2)>0));"NOT SORTED";"SORTED"))
```

for C3 use this and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11;B3)=1;"UNIQUE";IF(OR(IFERROR(MAX($C$2:C2*($B$2:B2=B3));0)>C3;AND(IFERROR(MAX(C4:$C$11*(B4:$B$11=B3));0)<C3;COUNTIF(B4:$B$11;B3)>0));"NOT SORTED";"SORTED"))
```

Comment: Nice. You clearly understood the requirements better than I did.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, could you please suggest another way around, since I don't have access to MAXIFS, because of not having access to Office 365

Comment: I edit the answer and completed a solution for none 365 user.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris, really appreciate your help!

Comment: With pleasure. If the answer helps you, maybe you can vote it and set it as answered.?!

Answer (score 0):

Such a lookup is now relatively easy with the new XLookup function.

I tried to re-engineer the logic in your data sample, but there must be some typo or thinking error.

Scenario 1: If "sorted" means that the next number can only be 1 larger than the previous number, then A=12 should not be "sorted".  The formula is

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"sorted","unique"),0,-1)="unique","unique",
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,"sorted",0,-1)="sorted","sorted",
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,,0,-1)-B2>1,"sorted","not sorted"
)))
```

Scenario 2:If, however, "sorted" means that the number in that row is bigger than the last number for this article, then B=15 should be "sorted". The formula is

```
=IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"sorted","unique"),0,-1)="unique","unique",
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,"sorted",0,-1)="sorted","sorted",
IF(XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,,0,-1)<B2,"sorted","not sorted"
)))
```

[image]

With the new Let() function, the repeated Xlookups can be avoided.

```
=LET(
x,XLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:A1,$B$1:B1,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"sorted","unique"),0,-1),
result,IF(ISTEXT(x),x,IF(x<B2,"sorted","not sorted")),
result)
```

XLookup is available in Office 365 versions of Excel.
Let is currently in preview and only available in Insider/Beta builds of Office 365.

Comment: Appreciate your effort Could you please suggest a way by not using XLOOKUP, since I don't have access to Office365 currently